# How to run coded UI tests from TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, automated-tests, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

I'm new to Coded UI testing and TFS. I've written a coded UI test for my web application and looking for different options to automatically run it. Apparently the first option is to run it from visual studio. I have also found an article explaining how to associate a test method with a test case however I don't know whether I can run my test method (s) from TFS or not? How about running them with my build? I know the unit tests can be run with the build however I'm not sure about coded UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for you to run Coded UI test in the TFS build process.

Firstly, you need to configure the Team Build Service Host run as an interactive process. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx#interactive).

Secondly, add the Coded UI test project into TFS Version Control.

Thirdly, create a build definition to build the Coded UI test project, and also specify tests to run.

Please have a check of this blog for the detailed steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/05/26/coded-ui-test-in-a-team-build.aspx

Comment: Do I need to install VS 2015 Enterprise in TFS server to execute Coded UI Tests?

Comment: The second link is dead